# How to do Node.js application resources profiling

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, express, sails.js

While building Node.js applications, how to monitor my code behaviour in memory and IO, knowing for sure what blocks and and what doesn't, what most consumes my memory/processor at what operation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2) to monitor your application process. If you want profiling, use Keymetric (also by PM2 team). It also has other benefits like auto restart if your application exited.